# help with jquery functions?

Tags: jquery, function, html-lists

Okay, so I am creating a ticker of sorts, and I had some pretty good code but it could only be used with one unordered list per page. So I though I might be able to just put it into a function and designate which ul follow the function, this is what I have so far:

```
function addTicker(ul) {
var ticker = $(' + ul + ');
ticker.children(':first').show().siblings().hide();

setInterval(function() {
    ticker.find(':visible').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(ticker);
        ticker.children(':first').show();
    });
}, 2000);
}

addTicker("ul.ticker");
```

But when I try to implement it, it doesn't do anything.

I have taken a Java course before, but I am just a tad unfamiliar with JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error on the first line of the `addTicker` function, this should work:

```
var ticker = $(ul);
```

Also, Java != JavaScript.

Comment: Java != JavaScript: well aware. ha

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you arent referencing the function parameter...

You are using a string which is `' + ul + '`

Try this:

```
function addTicker(ul) {
var ticker = $(ul);
ticker.children(':first').show().siblings().hide();

setInterval(function() {
    ticker.find(':visible').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(ticker);
        ticker.children(':first').show();
    });
}, 2000);
}

addTicker("ul.ticker");
```

Note, now the variable `ticker` is using the parameter from the function :)

Hope that helps :)